# Related articles links at the end of each article - SEO

Tags: seo, blog

I have some blogs and I was wondering if adding a list of internal "related articles" at the end of each article can be a good SEO practice.

From the visitor's perspective, they might be able to find articles they can be interested in.

I was thinking to limit the list to just 5 so it won't look very spammy.
Any thoughts or articles on this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very good SEO practice to link your articles together.  It is both good for users and good for crawlers.  Users find more articles in which they might be interested.   Crawlers pass link juice around your site much better and your site ends up ranking better.

In effect, linking your articles changes the information architecture of your site.  Your link structure becomes a true "web" of links rather than being linked as a "tree", "star", or "snowflake".  A web is much easier for search engines to crawl and process because every page has multiple other pages linking into it.  When you rely only on central pages like the home page and categories to do all the linking, many article pages may end up with just one link and very little love.

I recommend interlinking leaf pages such as articles or product pages in many of my answers here.   This site itself has a "Related Questions" section in the right hand navigation for this purpose.

Limiting the list to just 5 links sounds OK, but it is very common to see up to 10 related links.  You could consider having more links without making it look spammy.

For further reading: [SEO Journal: Related Articles & Internal Linking: Will It Help Your SEO Results?](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/related-articles-internal-linking-seo/256559/)

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks for that!